# Manhua where a woman who is dying of cancer finds her husband cheating on her

Tags: story-identification, manga

I saw a TikTok about this manhua a few days ago and I cannot remember the name of it for the life of me. I only saw a few stills, but from what I saw, the Main Character, a woman dying of cancer, finds her husband cheating on her with her friend(?). She yells at the two, only to be beaten by the husband before falling and hitting her head on the corner of a table. She soon dies, but wakes up at some point in the past. I'd like to give the story a try but I can't find anything based on my searches. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

*[Marry My Husband](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/marry-my-husband/list?title_no=4572&page=1)* by sungsojak and LICO

[image: Front cover of Marry My Husband]

> When Jiwon, a 37-year-old cancer patient, walks in on her husband and best friend, she realizes her whole life has been a lie. What’s worse, she dies a tragic death at the hands of her husband. Would things have been different if she had made different choices? Fortunately for Jiwon, she is given the chance to rewrite her fate when she is reincarnated as her younger self. This time, she vows to live a happy life. But first comes revenge. Her plan? To marry off her now former best friend to her lying, cheating husband.

Comment: It would be great if you added a bit more details to this!